# how to replace null values from database with empty string in chain for functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, lodash

I'm using lodash and have this code right now

```
data: _(responseData.data)
     .pick(['title', 'layout', 'slug', 'author', 'seo', 'css', 'js'])
     .mapKeys((value, key) => _.camelCase(key))
     .value()
```

Some of the values can be returned as null from the database. I would like to replace null values with an empty string -> '' but I'm not sure how to chain another function to above chain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`_.mapValues()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#mapValues) to iterate the values, and check with [`_.isNull()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#isNull) if the value is `null`.

**Note:** if you want to handle `undefined` values as well, replace `_.isNull()` with [`_.isNil()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#isNil).

```js
const responseData = {
  data: {
    'title': 'title',
    'layout': null,
    'slug': null,
    'author': 'author',
    'seo': 'seo',
    'css': 'css',
    'js': 'js'
  }
}

const data = _(responseData.data)
  .pick(['title', 'layout', 'slug', 'author', 'seo', 'css', 'js'])
  .mapKeys((value, key) => _.camelCase(key))
  .mapValues(value => _.isNull(value) ? '' : value)
  .value()

console.log(data)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `||` Operator

```
_((responseData && responseData.data) || {})
     .pick(['title', 'layout', 'slug', 'author', 'seo', 'css', 'js'])
     .mapKeys((value, key) => _.camelCase(key))
     .value()
```

Comment: if css is returned as null, will your code turn it into an empty string instead of null? I'm not sure that will happen, you just replaced the whole of returned data with an empty object

Comment: If `responseData` is null, the final value will be an empty object. I think it's more consistent to return an object in both empty and non-empty situation. Do you want to return an empty string instead?